# Linked list deletion and duplication

Tags: c++, c, linked-list

In the code I copied `newnode` to the `head`node and also to the `temp` node. But when I delete an instance of data, it seems to affect the other locations as well. When I freed `newnode` it also erases the content of `head` and `temp` .How is this happening?

Though I copied data initially, the data is freed. This is due to dereferencing? So what should I do if I want to have a copy list and want to manipulate this without affecting the original?

And I initially malloc'd the memory I want by `malloc()` but in later copy operations I see at codes they are not `malloc()`'ed rather just copied. And how is it still it working? Do my two questions have a relation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;   

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node*next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node*newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data=2;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    struct node*head=NULL;
    head=newnode;
    struct node*temp=newnode;

    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<head->data;
        head=head->next;
    }

    cout<<temp->data;
    free(newnode);
    free(head);
    cout<<temp->data;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: newnode and temp  are all pointing to the  same node. You delete  newnode and head (which is null).  I assume in this case free() overwrites the freed memory for debugging purposes and that is what you see with additional UB when you try to dereference freed memory.

Comment: Although this has nothing to do with your problem why are you using malloc in a c++ program?

Comment: @drescherjm C++ the C way :) New to .cpp files

Comment: So what should i do if i wanna copy a list. if i do  list1=list2  then if i  free()  the list1, the list2 will also get deleted. right?

Comment: You are not copying at all here. You are initializing pointers to point to the same location.

Comment: I would start by learning new and delete and drop malloc / free if this is a c++ application.

Comment: So how do i copy rather than pointing to? Create a new list, traverse through it and copy node by node? Or how else to do it?

Comment: I could sense the c++ programmer in you :) i would definitely new and delete rather than malloc() and free() next time. Just saying :)

Comment: ***Create a new list, traverse through it and copy node by node?*** Yes.

Comment: ***could sense the c++ programmer in you :)*** I have written well over 1 million lines of c++ code at the day job (18 years).

Comment: So copying takes linear time? No other go?

Comment: ***So copying takes linear time?*** Yes.

Comment: **I have written well over 1 million lines of c++ code at the day job** great and thanks for your help :D you can now free() this question. oops delete it from your memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `struct node *newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` you allocate a piece of memory for a node once and then you assign the address of this memory to all other node pointers. So when you free this piece of memory, the node isn't available any more to any of the node pointers.

```
struct node *head=newnode;    // head now points to *newnode
struct node *temp=newnode;    // temp now also points to *newnode
...
free(newnode);    // newnode, head and temp point to released memory now
free(head);       // oops! head was released already by the previous statement
```

Note: this is the C explanation. In C++ the constructor of a class can do the memory allocation and a redefined assignment operator can create a new instance of the object (but I am not a C++ programmer).

The following function creates a copy of the list:

```
struct node *copylist(struct node *oldlist)
{
    struct node *newhead, *list;
    if (!oldlist) return(0);
    list= newhead= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    *newhead= *oldlist;
    while (oldlist->next) {
        list->next= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        oldlist= oldlist->next;
        list= list->next;
        *list= *oldlist;
    }
    list->next= NULL;
    return(newhead);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul Ogilvie but what if i want to copy a list and manipulate on it without affecting the other

Comment: ...then you have to make a copy of the list. In C that is the "hard way" by mallocing new nodes, copying the data and establishing the pointers of the list. See latest edit